# What do the interrupt numbers mean in mpstat

Tags: linux, fedora, interrupts, system-monitoring, sysstat

I ran the command **mpstat -A** and the output is shown below

```
#### THESE ARE MY COMMENTS. THEY WERE NOT PART OF THE ACTUAL OUTPUT ####
Linux 5.5.13-200.fc31.x86_64 (bluegene)         03/04/20        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

#### FIRST TABLE ####
17:17:30     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
17:17:30     all    7.95   59.90    1.98    0.73    0.52    0.17    0.00    0.00    0.00   28.75
17:17:30       0    6.99   60.40    2.04    0.74    0.53    0.12    0.00    0.00    0.00   29.18
17:17:30       1    8.37   59.56    1.84    0.54    0.48    0.12    0.00    0.00    0.00   29.09
17:17:30       2    8.39   60.76    1.76    0.75    0.49    0.11    0.00    0.00    0.00   27.74
17:17:30       3    8.03   58.89    2.29    0.89    0.58    0.32    0.00    0.00    0.00   29.01

#### SECOND TABLE ####
17:17:30    NODE    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
17:17:30     all    7.95   59.90    1.98    0.73    0.52    0.17    0.00    0.00    0.00   28.75
17:17:30       0    7.95   59.90    1.98    0.73    0.52    0.17    0.00    0.00    0.00   28.75

#### THIRD TABLE ####
17:17:30     CPU    intr/s
17:17:30     all   4325.27
17:17:30       0   1168.69
17:17:30       1   1156.67
17:17:30       2   1145.64
17:17:30       3   1389.12

#### FOURTH TABLE: WHAT DO THESE NUMBERS MEAN ####
17:17:30     CPU        0/s        8/s        9/s       16/s      120/s      121/s      126/s      127/s      128/s      129/s      130/s      131/s      132/s      133/s      134/s      135/s      136/s      137/s      NMI/s      LOC/s      SPU/s      PMI/s      IWI/s      RTR/s      RES/s      CAL/s      TLB/s      TRM/s      THR/s      DFR/s      MCE/s      MCP/s      HYP/s      HRE/s      HVS/s      ERR/s      MIS/s      PIN/s      NPI/s      PIW/s
17:17:30       0       0.02       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.49       0.00       0.00       1.14       0.00       0.00       2.12       0.07     805.73       0.00       0.07       0.00       0.00     105.11     122.92     171.47       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
17:17:30       1       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.27       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.49       0.00       0.00       0.10       0.00       0.00       0.07     802.78       0.00       0.07       0.00       0.00     105.00     130.87     169.61       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
17:17:30       2       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.49       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.07     808.62       0.00       0.07       0.00       0.00      77.09     124.83     162.49       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
17:17:30       3       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00     219.48       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.49       0.00       0.00       6.09       0.00       0.00       0.06       0.00       0.07     808.52       0.00       0.07       0.00       0.00      85.50     116.46     168.26       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.01       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00

#### FIFTH TABLE: WHAT DO THESE NUMBERS MEAN ####
17:17:30     CPU       HI/s    TIMER/s   NET_TX/s   NET_RX/s    BLOCK/s IRQ_POLL/s  TASKLET/s    SCHED/s  HRTIMER/s      RCU/s
17:17:30       0       0.34     734.52       0.00       1.55       0.01       0.00       0.23     147.43       0.00     284.60
17:17:30       1       0.11     736.76       0.18       1.48       0.02       0.00       0.12     137.30       0.00     280.70
17:17:30       2       0.00     741.47       0.00       1.55       0.06       0.00       0.00     113.95       0.00     288.60
17:17:30       3       0.00     739.52       0.01       7.66     218.59       0.00       0.26     144.30       0.00     278.77
```

As per the man pages I can understand the information in the first two tables

- The first table shows CPU utilization
- The second table shows NODE utilization

My questions are

- Does the third table shows interrupts/second
- What do the fourth and fifth table represent above and what do those columns mean

Answer (score 2):

This question was months ago but I thought I would drop a little info out here for any google search results.

The data from the 4th table is taken from the `/proc/interrupts` file. This file should provide a bit of a description for the non-numeric values. As for the numerics, they are identified by the hardware they are associated with, such as a drive, a console connection or a network interface.

The data in the 5th table is taken from the `/proc/softirqs` file. There isn't a description for these items but many of them are available via searches. TIMERS references kernel timers, NET* are network transmit/receive, etc.

Comment: I actually received an answer from the author of mpstat. I will add that to your answer as well, I forgot to add the answer.